# How to attach an event handler to an EnvDTE.Window

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vsix

I can open a new browser window in Visual Studio and open an url in it with the following snippet of code. The last line sets the title of this window to "newTitle". However, once the window is finished loading, the caption is updated to reflect the content of the URL. I like to attach an event handler to the window or to the embedded object, but I do not know how to do that.

```
var dte2 = Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(SDTE)) as DTE2;
var window = dte2.ItemOperations.Navigate(url, EnvDTE.vsNavigateOptions.vsNavigateOptionsNewWindow);
window.Caption = "newTitle";
```

What have I tried:

1. Check if the object inside the window is of type `vsWindowKindWebBrowser` and cast that object to `WebBrowser`. But `window.Object` cannot be cast to `WebBrowser`; `wb1` is null.

   ```
   var wb1 = window.Object as System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser;
   wb1.DocumentCompleted += (o, e) => { window.Caption = "newTitle"; };
   ```
2. Used the approach listed here: [How to Get List of Open Web Pages in Visual Studio Using EnvDTE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149785/how-to-get-list-of-open-web-pages-in-visual-studio-using-envdte/14268028#14268028). `wb2` is not `null` but the object inside is disposed, thus also of no use.

   ```
   var wb2 = new VisualStudioWebBrowser(window.Object);
   wb2.DocumentCompleted += (o, e) => { window.Caption = "newTitle"; };
   ```
3. Asked this question on MSDN, see [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a9c79034-ceb1-41e1-8476-3d312d90bdab), but no useful answer.

**Question**: How to attach an event handler to an `EnvDTE.Window` such that I can listen for the event that the page is finished loading?